# Partial matching address search on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, search

I have a database containing companies and their respective addresses which is an sql structure:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| company_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| city       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| street     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| house      | varchar(5)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| corp       | varchar(2)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| litera     | varchar(4)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| office     | int(25)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And i have a single search field, where people most likely will query the database with a city or street or both. Here's the problem:

I have no idea what their input will be like. I mean it's almost impossible that they will search for something like "44" without at least specifying a street, but they still have a lot of options. I'll give a couple of search terms:

```
"Moscow" [just the city]
"Moscow, Leningradsky" [city AND street not including the type of the 
  street - which is "prospekt" ~ "avenue" in english]
"Moscow, Leningradsky pr[ospekt] [city AND street including the type of the 
  street, which may be shortened]
"Moscow, [ulitsa] Uralskaya [ulitsa] [city AND street where type can 
  preceed or succeed the street name itself (ulitsa meaning "street")]
```

And some other options. My first idead was something like take their term and search with LIKE both in the city and street columns, but what if they enter two words? I can't even be sure that the first word would be a city (cause
they might just start with the street having house number as the second word).

So i kind of searched for partial matching and fuzzy search, but couldn't really figure out how to put it together to work.

Do people have any best pracitces on this one?

Comment: You should investigate full text search.

Comment: Sometimes I would add another field to the table and just have the full address as text, as above full text search. Defining a list of block words may help 'prospekt' etc. and some hard coded replacements. What about spelling mistakes :)